# Executing code asynchronously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am currently learning how to use Angular.js and was attempting to write my own authentication code using a REST-like API. Below is the code for my authentication service.

The problem with my `signIn` function is that it always returns false, even when my api returns `HTTP 200`. After some time, I figured out that it is because of the synchronous nature of javascript that the `return response;` statement is executed before the `response = res.data.key;` statement.

I don't know how to execute the return statement after the assignment is complete (if the response is `HTTP 200`). How do I do this?

```
angular.module('app').factory('auth', ['Base64', '$http', function(Base64, $http) {
    return {
        signIn: function(email, password) {
            var response = false;
            var encoded = Base64.encode(email + ':' + password);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
            $http.post('api/v1/sign_in', {}).then(function(res) {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    response = res.data.key;
                }
            });
            return response;
        }    
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$q.defer()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
angular.module('app').factory('auth', ['Base64', '$http', '$q', function(Base64, $http, '$q') {
    return {
        signIn: function(email, password) {
            var response = false;
            // You create a deferred object
            // that will return a promise
            // when you get the response, you either :
            // - resolve the promise with result
            // - reject the promise with an error
            var def = $q.defer();
            var encoded = Base64.encode(email + ':' + password);
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
            $http.post('api/v1/sign_in', {}).then(function(res) {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    response = res.data.key;
                    // success: we resolve the promise
                    def.resolve(response);
                } else {
                  // failure: we reject the promise
                  def.reject(res.status);
                }
            });
            // You return the promise object that will wait 
            // until the promise is resolved
            return def.promise;
        }    
    }
}]);
```

Now, you can do:

```
auth.signIn().then(function(key) {
    // signin successful
    // do something with key
}).catch(function(err) {
    // signin failed :(
    // do something with err
}).finally(function() {
    // you could do something in case of failure and success
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about promises: return the promise from the http post.

[This may help](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)